# Should a ViewController handle actions of view's subviews as well?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

In my project, I tend to add a tableView, moviePlayer, and few more subviews to my views.
All the IBActions of the buttons in subviews and also it becomes datasource and delegate  for the tableView in it.

As a result of it the ViewController has become a very big class.

Should my subviews have a different controller ? then how do I communicate between these sub-controllers and my view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have different kinds of logic on one screen you actually should devide them to different UIViewControllers with their own nib-files. To communicate with them you can youse NSNotifications: push notifications on IBActions and catch them in your subview-controllers.

Comment: Nope, just use a set of UIViewControllers.

Comment: Why Notification ? wont setting a delegate do ?

Comment: You can, but notifications are more easy when there are not too many of them :)

Answer (score 0):

Not really. A view controller is the heart of your shiny Cocoa applications, and according to Apple's docs, they're the preferred way to implement glue code. No need for more layers in such a simple case.

Comment: Is it fine if your class goes above 1000 of line ?

Comment: Why not? Large projects have millions of lines, but not as many classes.

Comment: It will be extremely difficult to maintain that class - you will be just unable to find the code you need to fix quickly.